how to use next-i18next in nextjs V14 in App Router convetion?
I read the document and configured the project according to it, but it didn't work. The relevant code is below:
// next.config.js
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config')

module.exports = {
    i18n,
}

// next-i18next.config
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'ch',
        locales: ['ch'],
    },
}

// page.tsx
'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styles from "@/app/translate/page.module.css"
import appStyles from "@/app/page.module.css"
import { StepProps, Steps } from "antd";
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

export default function Teanslate() {
    const { t } = useTranslation('common')
    const stepItems:StepProps[]=[
        {
            title:t("uploadFile")
        },
        {
            title:t("trConfig")
        }
    ]
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
    return (
        <div className={appStyles.main}>
            <p>{t("trConfig")}</p>
            <Steps current={current} items={stepItems}></Steps>
        </div>
    )
}

// common.json
{
    "uploadFile":"上传文件",
    "trConfig":"翻译配置"

}

The project structure:

i have marked the relevant file
this is the result that page render

I hope the translation could work

i solved it.Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8tnD2BWY28&t=912s&ab_channel=i18nexus, if u have same problem
